# A distro that supports intel/nvidia hybrid graphics out of the box

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics, intel-graphics

I've spent so much time trying to get various flavours of Linux to run on my Dell XPS LS02 laptop which only has a HDMI output.

I've tried all sorts of solutions and methods including http://bumblebee-project.org/ However none have managed to get me a stable second display working.

The question, is there any distribution that supports the intel/nvidia(optimus) hybrid chipset out of the box?

Comment: Try Manjaro Linux with KDE desktop. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know you say you've tried the bumblebee-project but this would seem to be your best chance of getting this hardware to work. I found this tutorial and it seems straightforward:

- [How To Make NVIDIA’s Optimus Work on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/124685/how-to-make-nvidias-optimus-work-on-linux/)

I would take a second look at trying to get the 2nd display working through this setup, given there don't seem to be many other leads.

The Bumblebee project's wiki has this topic which I would try for starters:

- [Multi monitor setup](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup)

Comment: Thanks slm, I've tried more than a few times sadly :(

I just had one last attempt, following both your links, including the 3 potential solutions in the github multi monitor setup, alas no dice.

Options for me is buying a new laptop :(